# Returning an Array within an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My plugin modifies the price of products based on a value set within its options. It deducts a percentage off the product prices that have their ID included by me when I initiate it.

Firstly, Here is a stripped down version of the entire plugin (See comments within):

```
(function($) {
 $.fn.TTprices = function(options) {
  // Default Settings
  //
  var settings = $.extend({
   threshold: 1,
   discount: 40, // Initial Amount
   products: [],
  }, options);

return this.each(function() {
// Variables
 var $this = $(this);
 var $value = $this.contents()[0].textContent;
 var $price = parseFloat($value);
 var $discount = settings.discount;
 var $total = $price - ($price * $discount);
 var $productID = $this.data('product-id');
 var $products = (settings.products);
 var $saleTag = $this.find("span[data-badge='priceline']"); // Sale Tag for new price

 $this.html(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $products.length; i++) {

   var item = $products[i];

// The $productID need to be an array (My issue is here)
// 
if (item.id == $productID) { 
    if ($value >= (settings.threshold)) {

     var extraDiscount = item.extraDiscount ? item.extraDiscount : 0; // for calculting discount

     $discount = ($discount + extraDiscount) / 100;
     $total = $price - ($price * $discount);
     $saleTag.html(($discount * 100) + '% OFF');

     return $this.html().replace($value, $total.toFixed(2) + " ");

    }
   }
  }

  $saleTag.empty();
  return $this.html();
 });

});

 };
}(jQuery));
```

When the plugin is initiated it adds an extra discount to certain IDs. This is where I am looking to return an array of ID's and not just one! (I add the ID's manually.) Below is how i call the plugin and as you can see `products` options is an array. the `ID` within needs to return an array. How can I achieve this?

```
$('.price').TTprices({
 discount: 50,
 products: [{
  id: 'a1', // Here should be an array
  extraDiscount: 10
 }, {
  id: 'a2'// Here should be an array
 }, {
  id: 'a3',// Here should be an array
  extraDiscount: 30
 }],
});
```

Essentially it should look something like this:

```
$('.price').TTprices({
 discount: 50,
 products: [{
  id: ['a1'],
  extraDiscount: 10
 }, {
  id: ['a1','a2','a3'], // an array
  extraDiscount: 20

 }],
});
```

**Jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/panoply/2cqv9ar7/

Comment: If I understand you just want the plugin to handle an array of Ids instead of a single value? Would just mean wrapping that code in a loop for each productId ?

Answer (score 0):

To handle an array of ids:

```
var itemIds = $products[i].id;

// The $productID need to be an array (My issue is here)
// 
var inArray = false;
for(var j = 0; j < itemIds.length; j++){
    if (itemIds[j] == $productID) { 
        inArray = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (inArray) { 
     ....
```

Comment: This issue here is then the product is no longer recognised as an array. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/panoply/2cqv9ar7/2/ (see where it is initiated).

Comment: I updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2cqv9ar7/5/ the loop variable i was reused, i changed it to j. This corrects the result.